# Function does not work inside a class - function call missing argument list

Tags: c++, windows, hook, keylogger

I've built a working keylogger and now I want to move it to class so I can re-use it whenever I want and even on different languages like c# however I encountered error because same code does not work inside a class.

### main.cpp (working)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

void main()
{
    HINSTANCE h_instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0); // Works here
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Populate typedChars
    return NULL;
}
```

### KeyboardHook.cpp (not working)

```
class KeyboardHook
{
    stringstream typedChars;

    LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        // Populate typedChars
        return NULL;
    }

    KeyboardHook()
    {
        HINSTANCE h_instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0); // Does not work
    }

public:
    std::string Get()
    {
        return typedChars.str();
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        typedChars.str(std::string());
        typedChars.clear();
    }
};
```

### Error

```
C3867: 'KeyboardHook::KeyboardProc': function call missing argument list; use '&KeyboardHook::KeyboardProc' to create a pointer to member
```

So I modify it to `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0);` and now different error occurs

```
C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

I've also tried but no success:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (LRESULT)&KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0);
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (LRESULT)KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0);
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHook::KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0);
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyboardHook::KeyboardProc, h_instance, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SetWindowsHookEx` is supposed to take a function pointer (I can never understand the [horrible Windows API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), you need to bind your pointer to member function to an object on which it should be called. If you want to bind it to the object pointed to by `this` (i.e. the `KeyboardHook` object you're creating at the time), try this:

```
using std::placeholders;
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
  std::bind(&KeyboardHook::KeyboardProc, this, _1, _2, _3),
  h_instance, 0);
```

Alternatively, `KeyboardProc` can be declared as a static member function, but that means it won't be able to use the `typedChars` member.

Comment: I get `C2039: 'placeholders' : is not a member of 'std'` as well as `_1 .. _3` are undefined. Making them static solves everything but generates huge problem - I cannot add hooked strokes to `stringstream`.

Comment: @Steve `std::bind` is part of C++11 - make sure your compiler supports it. Also make sure you're including `<functional>`.

Comment: Okey now I did added `<functional>` and it found the `std::bind` but still have error, it seems it did not take any effect. `C2664: 'SetWindowsHookExA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' to 'HOOKPROC'` any ideas?

Comment: WinAPI is C programming interface, so passing it function object (what `std::bind` actually returns) won't work. Only static functions will.

Comment: This answer is invalid, why it was accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You must define `KeyboardProc` as a static member

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
...
}
```

if it must and can be called without an object.